# My webpage should be printing out a string of digits, but isn't

Tags: javascript, html

Any idea why the following code isn't working? It should be creating a webpage that is just a string of digits (via a reversible encryption scheme that you can see in the function `encrypt()`). Yet all that happens is that `document.write(encrypt("Yo, dawg, I heard you like functions"));` gets printed at the top of the web page.

```
<html>



<head>
    <title>Simple encrypt/decrypt</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function encrypt(thisString)
        {
            retString = "";
            /* Make retString a string of the bit representations of 
               the ASCII values of its characters in order.
            */
            for (i = 0, j = thisString.length; i < j; i++) 
            { 
                bits = thisString.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
                retString += new Array(8-bits.length+1).join('0') + bits;
            }
            /* Compress retString by taking each substring of 3, 4, ..., 9 
               consecutive 1's or 0's and it by the number of such consecutive
               characters followed by the character. 
               EXAMPLES:
                    "10101000010111" --> "10101401031"
                    "001100011111111111111" --> "0011319151"
            */
            retString.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) { return ($0.length + $1);});

            return retString;
        } 


    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <script="text/javascript">
        document.write(encrypt("Yo, dawg, I heard you like functions"));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yo, dawg, I see you don't like jsfiddle?

Comment: it should be `retString = retString.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) { return ($0.length + $1);});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
<script="text/javascript">
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Now I'm going to get downvoted for posting a bug that was a type-o ..... in 3 ... 2 ... 1 ....